# Change the state of one item in a map in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a page that displays images fetched with an api call using the map method. Now what I want to do is to toggle the like or unlike state of `FavoriteIcon` by clicking it.

When I try to implement that using the `useState` hook, if I click on the `FavoriteIcon` in a single image, all the images are set to the same state. I want only the clicked image to change its state.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import FavoriteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite";
import FavoriteBorderIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorder";

// services
import medias from "../../services/mediaServices";

function Favorites({ fetchUrl, catagory }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [images, setImages] = useState([{}]);
  
  const [favIcon, setFavIcon] = useState();

 

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getData() {
        const request = await medias.getMedias(fetchUrl);
        setImages(request.data.message);  
    }
    getData();
  }, [fetchUrl, enqueueSnackbar, closeSnackbar]);

 
  return (
    <div className={classes.favorites}>
      <div className={classes.favorites__items}>
          {images &&
            images.map(image => {
              return (
                  <div
                    elevation={3}
                    className={classes.favorites__posters}
                    style={
                      {
                        //   border: "2px solid black"
                      }
                    }
                  >
                    <img
                      key={image.id}
                      src={image.thumbnailUrl}
                      alt={image.title}
                    />
                    {favIcon ? (
                      <FavoriteIcon onClick={() => setFavIcon(false)} />
                    ) : (
                      <FavoriteBorderIcon onClick={() => setFavIcon(true)} />
                    )}
                  </div>      
              );
            })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Favorites;
```

Comment: You should create a component called `Image` or anything and do all the logic of fav icon in that component.

Answer (score 0):

Without breaking it into more components, your `favIcon` state needs to contain the state of all your icons.  It should be initialized with something like

`images.map(image => {id: image.id, state: false})`

and then you could change your `onClick` to just update the relevant part of state

`setFavIcon([...favIcon].map(x => {if(x.id === image.id) {x.state = !x.state}; return x}))`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you be more specific. Where do I put {id: image.id, state: false}).

Comment: Probably after the `setImages`